# CSS Dropdown Menu Problem

Tags: css, wordpress, menu, drop-down-menu

i have a Problem with my Wordpress Design, specialy with Dropdownmenu.

http://fincha.com/wordpress/

Check this, in the main menu "Versicherungen" you will see, i tryed allready all combinations with z-index... without results. :(

if some one have a nice idea for this menu, just tell :)

thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand the reason for this myself (though I didn't research it; maybe a more experienced user can tell me), but `z-index` properties are only respected when the element is *not* `position`ed `static`ally. Your problem is fixed by adding

```
#mainmenu {
    position: relative;
}
```

so by including `position: relative;` for `#mainmenu` (your declaration starts on line 46 of style.css).